# jQuery mobile with maskedinput

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, input, mask

I'm using the plugin to mask my input phone (jquery.maskedinput.js - http://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/).
But I need to implement .mask() to change it at runtime so the mask:

```
$("#inputPhone").onkeypress(function(){
    if($(this).val() === "119999"){
       $(this).mask("(99) 99999-9999");
    } else {
       $(this).mask("(99) 9999-9999");
    }
});
```

The problem that is happening, when changing .mask() temp in implementing the value set during execution is being lost.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: try to call `unmask()` first

Comment: Also "119999" doesn't seem to fit in "(99) 999..."